# How to Work a JQUERY function after checking the MYSQL in PHP

Tags: php, jquery, mysql

I have a jQuery function named Update.

If $_SESSSION['Name'] is set, then the Update function of jQuery should be executed.

How can I do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Place a check for this in PHP, and if it is set, then print the code to the page to execute the JS function.

```
<?php

if(isset($_SESSION['Name'])){
    //execute the JavaScript/jQuery Update function
    ?>
    <script>
       Update();
    </script>
    <?php
  }
```

Comment: Note that this must be *after* the script tag that loads jQuery.

Answer (score 2):

jQuery is a frontend technology, whereas PHP (and therefore $_SESSION) are backend technologies. Because of this, jQuery cannot directly access the $_SESSION variable.

You could create a PHP file to check for the existence of the session variable, though, and use an AJAX call to retrieve that information from the frontend.